# Can Launching of EC2 Instances be Restricted to Certain Hours of the Day?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to restrict launching of EC2 instances between the hours of 8:00 AM to 7:00 PM, Monday through Friday, for external contractors (cost-cutting purposes).  I found date `Condition` operators [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Conditions_Date).  However, there is nothing that allows me to setup a pattern or regular expression to create a daily schedule of enablement.

Have I not found it, or does it simply not exist?  And, if it doesn't exist, is there a way I can make use of what does exist to do what I want?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: check this out: https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/stop-start-ec2-instances/

Comment: @aldanux it probably works but it's a lot of work compared to the solution using lambda jobs outline below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do a regex/pattern. 
What you can do is generate time intervals for each day (via a script of course) and do a logical OR on all the conditions. This is somewhat of a mess and would be hard to maintain / understand. You will also probably run into some sort of limits with the policy size.

What I would do is: have 2 policy templates. one allowing you to launch instances, the other not. Schedule a lambda job for when you want to disable/enable the job. The Lambda should just update the policy.

Comment: I thought it might involve 2 IAM policies like you described.  I was thinking about using a 'cron' job with the AWS CLI.  I hadn't thought of using Lambda.  I like that idea better, thanks!